# Clicking checkbox for website with only div class available

Tags: html, excel, vba, checkbox

HTML Code

```
<div class="_2yjv">
<input type="checkbox">
```

VBA Code

```
'Click check box
Dim cbox As Object
    Set cbox = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("_2yjv")(0)
    cbox.Click
```

Hi, I have been trying to put a check on a checkbox for a couple of hours now and have tried the following:

- cbox.Click
- cbox.DoubleClick
- cbox.Value = True
- cbox.Checked = True
- cbox.Value = 1

cbox.Click and cbox.DoubleClick had no errors, but is not doing anything. 
The rest shows errors. It's the only checkbox from a popup window.

I've been searching this forum and others but they usually have the name value on them, and I can only find those two lines from inspect element which points to the checkbox button. Would really appreciate any help on this. I'm new and still learning VBA. Thank you.

Comment: You try to 'check' the div element. You must 'check' the input element: `cbox.FirstChild.Checked = True` or `cbox.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Checked = True`

Comment: Hi @Zwenn, the first option did put a tick on the checkbox, the only problem now is it's not triggering the "Okay" button which lights up when the checkbox is clicked manually. 

Thank you for your help, this is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you must trigger a html event of the checkbox. Look here how to trigger an event: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61680941/select-an-option-from-a-dropdown-in-ie-and-triggering-a-function/61696514#61696514

Comment: Hi @Zwenn, thanks again for your help. I just changed cbox.FirstChild.Checked = True to cbox.FirstChild.Click. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Zwenn, `cbox.FirstChild.Click` did the trick.